# How to rebuild node modules after node.js version upgrade?

Tags: node.js, npm

I upgraded my node.js version from 9.x.x to a version 12.x.x. Do i now need to rebuild all my old node modules to "bind" them to the new node.js version? How is it done? What if i run command (from windows) "npm rebuild /node_modules" (put the whole folder as parameter)? Will it work?

EDIT: Perhaps this was a useless question. It looks like i needed only to rebuild node-sass-module, not others.

Comment: run `npm ci` , or delete `node_modules` and run `npm i`, which is what `npm ci` does.

Answer (score -1):

After node version update i only needed to reduild node-sass module. I thought i have to do a similar rebuild to all modules i use, but all the other npm modules work without problems.